# Can i use (insert , update etc) an SQL database that comes from a replication server (subscriber side)

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have an ERP program that uses an SQL database. I want to somehow duplicate it and then work with that specific duplicated version. When i say work , i mean add products, customers etc.

I used SQL Server Replication and tried it , which works . Almost.
My ERP with that database doesnt work , i mean it starts , it loads everything, but when i try to add a product for example , it says that it cant insert a null value.
I forgot to mention that except the fact that i want to use with that replicated database , i also want  to continue accepting data from replication server  . I mean if a product is added to the publisher side, i want it to be shown in  my replicated database.
Is all that even possible? or i am looking at the wrong side?